# Making a cURL GET request using pre-defined variables in C++

Tags: c++, http, curl, get

I am currently writing a C++ program on macOS which requires us to take two variables from the user, being the HWID and the IP address and use them in a get request like so;

```
CURL* curl;
string result;

curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "website.com/c.php?ip=" + ip + "&hwid=" + hwid);
```

This is how `hwid` and `ip` are defined;

```
auto hwid = al.exec("ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | awk '/IOPlatformUUID/ { print $3; }'");

auto ip = al.exec("dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com.");
```

Keep in mind al.exec is just a function that executes and returns the output of a terminal command.

However the issue with doing all of this, is I'm giving curl_easy_setopt incorrect types for params... I'm getting these errors when making the GET request like the example earlier;

```
Cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >' through variadic function; call will abort at runtime
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cURL library is a ***C*** library, all its functions are ***C*** functions. Therefore they can't handle object like `std::string`. And when you do `"website.com/c.php?ip=" + ip + "&hwid=" + hwid` the result *is* a `std::string` object.

One way to solve it is to save the result of `"website.com/c.php?ip=" + ip + "&hwid=" + hwid` in a variable, and then use that variable with the [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function to get a C-style string:

```
std::string url = "website.com/c.php?ip=" + ip + "&hwid=" + hwid;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should prepare a `const char*` to call `curl_easy_setopt()`:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "website.com/c.php?ip=" << ip << "&hwid=" << hwid;
std::string url = oss.str();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```